# "Camera Fit Frame to Selected" in Blender Python

Tags: python, camera, blender

I am simply looking for, if it exists in the Python scripting language for Blender, the function or method that performs the action "Camera Fit Frame to Selected". When you push the space bar in Blender, you can do exactly this, but I'm having a time finding it in the scripting documentation, or even finding the button for it in the UI.

Comment: if you haven't already, you can consider also asking in Blender Stackexchange - which is very active.

Comment: [Already answered here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/410/935)

Comment: Sorry. That doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: As I continue exploring the view menu it appears the Python call for "Align Active Camera to Selected" may do just the thing I need. I will update this question if I can confirm this.